# How can we Extract a BLOB data(image stored as blob) and display it in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Iam getting data in a service where iam getting a BLOB data consists of image data how can i extract it and display it in my UI

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from blob to base64 and display it using .

```
 let me = this;
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
 reader.onloadend = function() {
     me.base64data = 'data:image/png;base64,'+reader.result;                
     console.log(base64data);
 }
```

**Template**

```
<img [src]="base64data" width="100" height="50"/>
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer